# Netflix's way of ignoring the autoplay/muted broswer policy?

Tags: reactjs, video, autoplay, netflix

Netflix recommended video trailers play sounds even without the user interacting with the page first. How?

Comment: [Browsers generally require the user to interact with the video controls in the page and other heuristics](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2018/03/chrome-66-will-try-to-block-unwanted-noisy-autoplaying-video/) to determine that the user *wants* to play audio/visual content (as opposed to annoying video ads which no-one asked for and no-one wants and holy crap you're wasting _how much_ of my mobile data plan's bandwidth?!?). So how are you using `<video>` in your page? How are users interacting with it?

Comment: What do you mean by "Feature Component"?

Comment: I'm trying to use it just as Netflix does, if the user goes off the page the sound stops, but if he's in the page, the image fades and the video plays automatically through a reducer, play state is on just as "muted" attribute is off.

Comment: The thing is, if I have mute off and autoplay true the browser prevents me from playing the video and it stops

Comment: Thats why I'm asking if there is a way to overwrite the chrome policy just as Netflix does

Comment: @Dai I mean the component which usually have the trailer which covers 100vh of the screen and has those "play & additional info" buttons  aswell as the mute button on the right side

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome/#:%7E:text=Chrome%20allows%20autoplay%20for%20over%201%2C000%20sites%20where%20we%20see%20that%20the%20highest%20percentage%20of%20visitors%20play%20media%20with%20sound.), Chrome allows autoplay for over 1,000 sites where they see that the highest percentage of visitors play media with sound. And Netflix is also whitelisted.